# How copy files from dir1 to dir2 with names only existing in dir2, using only predefined tasks of MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have project template, unzipped in dir2 (with subfolders). And template's source project in dir1 (with subfolders). My task is to update all the files in dir2, which came earlier from dir1, with actual versions of files from dir1 (regardless whether they are updated or not, for simplicity). When I say "came earlier", I mean that they have the same name as files in dir1.

The problem is that there are files in dir1, not existing in dir2, and vice versa - and they mustn't be copied. And both dir1 and dir2 have subfolders, so it is not enough to just copy files, existing in both directories. All of them should be placed exactly in their appropriate subdirectories in dir2.

The question is - is it possible to do it not using inline tasks (C#/VB code)? I perfectly understand how to do it on C#/VB, but it is not perfect solution if I can do it with predefined MSBuild Tasks and Property Functions. BUT - up to now I haven't find the way to do it :-(.

Comment: A [build event property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-use-build-events-in-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2017) or [Exec Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2017#example) can help. Not knowing your project type, so I'm not certainly sure if your project type supports build-event. But I think the exec task can meet your needs.

Comment: And sorry for the last comment, there's something wrong with the link of Exec task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't mention that the destination directory is a subdirectory of the source directory. xcopy didn't work for me in such situation, even when I provided appropriate /EXCLUDE parameters, I got cycling error.

BUT - I found pure MSBuild solution, this is my variant:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectFiles Include="**" Exclude="obj\**;bin\**;bak\**" />
  <TemplateIntputs Include="@(ProjectFiles)" Condition="Exists('$(IntermediateTemplateSUBPath)%(ProjectFiles.Identity)')" />
  <TemplateOutputs Include="@(TemplateIntputs->'$(IntermediateTemplateSUBPath)%(Identity)')" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The key, obviously, is "Exists" function.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it not using inline tasks (C#/VB code)?

It's possible. Like what I mentioned in the comment. Build event property or Exec Task can achieve this goal.

**Step1:**

A cmd command `xcopy  path\Dir1 path\Dir2 /U /Y /E` can work as what you want.

The `/U` means only copy the files which exists in Dir2 to Dir2 from Dir1, just like an update of same-name files.(It works for both subfolders and files)

Suggestion:Use a cmd command to check if it works before Step2.

**Step2:**

For Msbuild Task [Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2017#example). Since now you are familiar with msbuild, so in short:

```
<Target Name="MyCopyCommand">
    <Exec Command="xcopy  path\Dir1 path\Dir2 /U /Y /E"/>
</Target>
```

In addition: You can add the content of the command into a xx.bat, and use it like:

```
<Target Name="MyCopyCommand">
        <Exec Command="path\xx.bat"/>
</Target>
```

And don't forget to control the order of the target, using DefaulTargets,AfterTargets,BeforeTargets to control when to run the copy command.

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Have a nice day!